# How to pick certain values from text files and print as array into a single output file

Tags: python

I only have very basic knowledge of python and the following problem:

I have a number of numbered text files *RA512_mono_1_M2_Ci_lex.stat* for i in [1..n].
All these files have the same format with lines such as

> Number of apples in sample:    x

(The line is always the same in every file, only x is different)

I would like to write a program that reads all n of these files and gives an output text file of the form

> [(1,x1),(2,x2),...,(n,xn)]

so that I can plot them.

I have a few problems, that I haven't figured out yet:

1. How do I read a value at a certain position in the input file
2. How do I loop over the counter in the filenames

What I have so far is not much:

```
graphdata = []
for i in range(1,n):
    with open('RA512_mono_1_M2_Ci_lex.stat') as file_in: #What is the correct syntax for looping over i?
        datapoint = #How do I pick the value I want?
            graphdata.append(datapoint)

np.savetxt('graph.out', graphdata, delimiter=',') #There might be a better way without numpy?
```

Of course, there is more syntax to be fixed.

Comment: So... What's your question? If you want to write a program, *write a program*.

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you *tried to do* but didn't work. Otherwise you are just asking people here to do your work for you. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288133/1391441

Comment: Can you make your question match your code? What numbered files are you referring to? And where are these apples of which you speak?

Comment: Edited as much and as best as I was able to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are in the same directory you could use os.listdir() (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) to get a list of your files you can then loop through.

To retrieve a value from a certain position you could use regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html):

```
import os
import re

path = your_file_path
d = os.listdir(path) # get list of file names

graphdata = []
pat = re.compile('(?<=\w\:\s)\d+')
for f in d:
    with open(path + f, 'r') as file:
        file = file.read()
        num = re.findall(pat, file)
        graphdata.append((f, num))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works almost perfectly.
I don't fully undestand the argument of re.compile() though.
Can I specify as a pattern _'the first integer in line x after `string`'_?

Edit: I don't have to specify the line as long as I can specify the string preceding the integer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is my final solution (thanks to @Benjamin):

```
import re

graphdata = []
pat = re.compile('\d+')
for i in range(1,n):
  f = open('RA512_mono_1_M2_C'+str(i)+'_lex.stat').readlines()[k-1]
  match = re.findall(pat, f)
  x = int(match[j-1])
  datapoint = (i,x)
  graphdata.append(datapoint)

with open('graph.out', 'w') as f:
  f.write(str(graphdata))
```

Picking the jth number in the kth line of every file in range(1,n) and printing the data as datapoints for a graph.